# how to find the difference between last two entries in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a solution regarding the Fine the difference between the last two entries difference in MySQL

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date,
       SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number
FROM tbl_order 
WHERE status = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m')
Limit 2
```

OutPut :

```
date     number
02/2019 2345.01
03/2019 103751.05
```

But i need an exact solution is i need to find the difference between the last 2 result

`2345.01 -103751.05`

Result :`-101406.04`
how to do in MySQL What is the Query?

Comment: I don't know too much about SQL but what date would your substraction have? I don't think the output would make much sense. Also, you use SUM already. Maybe you can find something out by using the minus operator, instead.

Comment: ok but my Question is  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order where status='Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') Limit 2         the output : date
number
02/2019
42345.01
03/2019
103751.05
 but i need diff between of last limit 2  case

Comment: I just read you can do stuff like SUM(-field).  Might be worth a try.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could try a cross join

```
select   a.date, a.number, b.number, a.number - b.number my_diff
from (

  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date
    , SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number 
  FROM tbl_order 
  where status='Confirmed' 
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') 
  Limit 2
)  a 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date
    , SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number 
  FROM tbl_order 
  where status='Confirmed' 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') 
) b ON a.date = b.date and a.number <> b.number
```

Comment: Showing Error: MySQL said: Documentation

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

One method is a `cross join`, but it looks like this:

```
SELECT last.number - last_1.number
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date,
             SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number
      FROM tbl_order 
      WHERE status = 'Confirmed'
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m')
      ORDER BY date
      LIMIT 1
     ) as last CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date,
             SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number
      FROM tbl_order 
      WHERE status = 'Confirmed'
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m')
      ORDER BY date
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
     ) last_1
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked but its calculate first two result  , but i need calculate last 2 group by result. if you have any idea ?

Comment: SELECT last.number - last_1.number FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order WHERE status = 'Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') ORDER BY date LIMIT 2 ) as last CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order WHERE status = 'Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') ORDER BY date LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2 ) last_1        Result: 
last.number - last_1.number
25583.21         
86989.25  i need to display last one value ???

Comment: how to displayed in PHP this SQL Statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last.number - last_1.number FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order WHERE status = 'Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ) as last CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%m/%Y') as date, SUM(order_total_after_tax) as number FROM tbl_order WHERE status = 'Confirmed' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_datetime,'%Y/%m') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 ) last_1
```